# How to get users with birthday today in plugin/module?

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, datetime

How does one retrieve users from Craft3 DB whose birthday is today?

Birthdate field type is Date/Time.

Have a working PHP/MySQL example, but unsure how to port this to Craft3 syntax.

```
$sql = 'SELECT 
            id,
            birthDate
         FROM 
            !
         WHERE 
            status = ?';


$users = $db->getAll($sql, array( USERS_TABLE, 
                                  'active', 
                                  date('j'),
                                  date('n')
                                ) 
                    );
```

Craft plugin

`$users = \craft\elements\User::find()
           ->group('siteUsers')
           ->status('active')
           ->all();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to get the results I needed by using the following query:

```
        $users = \craft\elements\User::find()
            ->where("extract(day from content.field_birthdate) = " . date('j'))
            ->andWhere("extract(month from content.field_birthdate) = " . date('n'))
            ->group('siteUsers')
            ->status('active')
            ->all();
```